# Trying to create a back button using HTTP REFERER and PHP that works even after page self reload

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, session-variables

I am trying to save the HTTP_REFERER to a $_SESSION[] variable and only updating it if the referring page does not match the current page. This way if I reload the page through a PHP script it does not save the current page I'm on as the referrer.

First I am getting the REFERER and comparing it to the current URL:

```
$referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
preg_match('/^(.*?\:\/\/)/', $referer, $start);
$url = $start[0].$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then I have an IF statement that says if they DONT match to update Session:

```
if($url != $referer){
     $_SESSION['referer'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
```

Then I check the output:

```
echo $_SESSION['referer'];
```

The issue is that it updates the session no matter what!

I have tried to do the same with cookies instead of the session variable. With cookies, I can see it changing in the consol. It won't update, and then a second later it updates. Almost as if the page is loading twice.

When I set this code

```
setcookie('test', $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

When I go to a new page, it will correctly display the correct refer, and then after a second, it switches to the current page.

My current setup uses .htaccess so that I don't have to type the file names of the pages. I have all requests of any subfolders go to /index.php

So http://example.com/home or http://example.com/coolpage will all go back to http://example.com/index.php

Then with PHP I look for the file named the same as that subfolder and then "include" it in my index.php file as a sort of simple templating system.

Are these .htaccess redirects messing with the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]? If I just use the $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] directly within my code it works fine (it's not updating). It's only when I try to save it to another variable that things go wonky.

Is there a better way to have a back button that sends the user back to where they came from without taking into account multiple page loads of the same URI?

Comment: I have not completely solved this issue. However, it seems to have something to do with the favicon.ico. This is getting requested after the page loads, and it's messing with the HTTP referer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that seems a bit odd, but it achieves the effect I want.

I wrap the whole thing in an if statement only executing if the $uri != favicon.ico

```
if($uri != 'favicon.ico'){
   $referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
   preg_match('/^(.*?\:\/\/)/', $referer, $start);
   $url = $start[0].$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

      if($url != $referer){
           $_SESSION['referer'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
      }

   $backButton = $_SESSION['referer'];  
}
```